# Sorting over a list inside a dataframe in R

Tags: r, list, sorting, lapply

I got a dataframe where a column (in this case, `V2`) is a list, like this:

```
df <- structure(list(V1 = c(1, 2, 3), 
                     V2 = list(c(1, 2, 78, 3), c(9, 4, 78, 8), c(33, 18, 25, 20, 10, 23))), 
                row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")

#  V1                     V2
#1  1            1, 2, 78, 3
#2  2            9, 4, 78, 8
#3  3 33, 18, 25, 20, 10, 23
```

I need to rearrange the elements on each row of `V2`. I've tried `lapply`ing a `sort` over `V2`, but can't get it to work.

Here is my desired output:

```
#  V1                     V2
#1  1            1, 2, 3, 78 
#2  2            4, 8, 9, 78
#3  3  10, 18, 20, 23, 25,33
```

Any suggestions are very much appreciated!

Comment: Have you searched for possible solutions? Can you show us what you've tried exactly?

Comment: Are you sure `lapply`ing a `sort` over `V2` does not work ? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply:

```r
df$V2 <- lapply(df$V2, sort)
```

Answer (score 0):

In `tidyverse`, we can use `map`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>%
    mutate(V2 = map(V2, sort))
df
#  V1                     V2
#1  1            1, 2, 3, 78
#2  2            4, 8, 9, 78
#3  3 10, 18, 20, 23, 25, 33
```